# Can not catch "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException" on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using route model binding for this route:

**api.php**

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
    Route::apiResource('applications', 'ApplicationController')->except(['index']);
});
```

and on the model:

**Application**

```php
/**
 * Get the route key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRouteKeyName(): string
{
    return 'client_id';
}
```

Here is part of my route-list:

```
| GET | HEAD | api/v1/applications/{application} | vms-direct-debit.applications.show  | App\Http\Controllers\ApplicationController@show  | api,auth:api |
```

In which, `client_id` is a string and suppose that `testclient` **DOES NOT EXIST** in `applications` table.
Well, when I call this route on `postman` or `insomnia`: `base_url/applications/testclient` (`GET`, show), it throws a `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException` Exception **AS I WANT**.

Okay, I want to catch this exception, so I use this code on `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`:

```php
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException) {
        return response()->json([
             'my-goddamn-custom' => 'message-here',
        ]);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

But I can not catch my custom response message. How can I catch my custom message response?

Comment: see this https://github.com/salmanzafar949/laravel-api-exceptions-handler

Comment: You can handle this error from a service provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.

I used `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` instead of `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException` exception.

**app/Exceptions/Handler.php**:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  Request $request
     * @param Exception $exception
     *
     * @return Response|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
            return response()->json([
             'my-goddamn-custom' => 'message-here',
        ]);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```